# How Billing works with internal IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-cloud-billing

If I create a custom network. lets say I have 2 subnets in the same network and If I try to communicate from VM-1 and VM-2 which are in subnet-1 and subnet-2 with the help of Internal IPs. Will be billed for egress?

Google docs says it will be billed for
between Zones
Across regions

But not mentioned about Internal or exteranl IPs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is in [general network pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general) is for egress through the Internal IP.

When using the External IP all egress is charged, even if the destination VM is in the same Zone. The details are in [Traffic through external IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#externaliptraffic).